# Get drive information

Tags: command-line, devices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which hard disk drive is which?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27997/which-hard-disk-drive-is-which)

How can I get more information about devices?

For example how do I determine what `/dev/sda1` is?

Comment: one of the answers here should be what you are looking for http://askubuntu.com/questions/27997/which-hard-disk-drive-is-which/28004#28004

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get information about the file system on the device use

```
udisks --show-info /dev/sda1
```

Use just *sda* instead of *sda1* to get information about the disk.