# Can't delete/edit files on my pendrive

Tags: trash, rm

I'm trying to delete the .Trash-1000 from my pen drive, but with

```
sudo rm -rf .Trash-1000/
```

I got

```
rm: cannot remove `.Trash-1000/expunged/2660089871/apps.log': Read-only file system
```

(one line of this for each file within `.Trash-1000/`)

I found [this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47538/how-to-make-read-only-file-system-writable), but I still got the same result after running:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw '/media/SGTL MSCN'
sudo rm -rf .Trash-1000
```

So, any idea how to remove this folder (or its content)?

*By the way, I need to remove it because I'm using the pen drive to test a software, and there's a file there that should not be found in the pen drive.*

**--update**

I thought it was corrupted, like Allan pointed, but the same just happened to another new pen drive I plugged here.. After use it on VMWare (in a new OS that still don't have a name), and go back to Ubuntu, I can no more edit it's files, nither make a filesystem check or format it.

Comment: Is there any reason you cant just reformat the whole drive?

Comment: @Allan Actually, I could backup the data, format it, and rewrite. It's a good workaround. But I really would like to understand why I can't delete the trash content, even with `sudo`.

Comment: Is it an ntfs/fat drive? Are you able to change the permissions of the folder and files using chmod?

Comment: @Allan It's properties says "Filesystem type: MSDOS", I'm not sure if this means ntfs/fat. And I'm not able to change anything using chmod, I get that same message about read-only. If I mount it as sudo, I don't get the message when using chmod, but it also has no effect.

Comment: Can you find the drive in Disk Utility?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/27997/which-hard-disk-drive-is-which/28004#28004

Comment: In the screen shot in the question there is a section called "device:" in this case /dev/sda what is yours for your pendrive?

Comment: ... Did you try empying the Trash folder on your computer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I were to guess it sounds to me like your Pendrive is corrupted.
the simple solution is to back-up and reformat however if you want to find out if it is really corrupted or not which could be a sign of a failing flash drive use `fsck`

first back-up your pendrive/card then find out what mount point its under eg. /dev/sdb , /dev/sdc etc.

You can find this information in [disk utility](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27997/which-hard-disk-drive-is-which/28004#28004) under the heading **Device:**

in the screen shot it is /dev/sdb1

You can then modify these commands and run each

```
sudo umount /media/disk

sudo fsck -favVr /dev/sdb1
```

Alternatively you can click "check file system" after unmounting the drive in disk utility

[image: Disk Utility]

Edit:

I have found another solution to this problem the steps are as follows

1. Mount the USB Drive you are having the problem with
2. Open Disk Utility as root open a terminal and enter `gksu palimpsest`
3. Unmount the Drive and remove
4. Plug it back in

Hopefully this will work if all else has failed

Comment: Yes, it's corrupted, I can't do a disk check or even format it. Thanks!

Comment: Yikes RIP Pendrive

Comment: ops, wait a second, the same just happened to another new pen drive I plugged here.. After some use, I can no more edit it's files, nither make a filesystem check or format it..

Comment: is it showing at all in disk utility or nautilus?

Comment: Yes it is, I discovered that VMWare or the OS have any problem with the Fat system. It's working ok as NFTS now.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similiar issue. I was doing a backup of a partition with "Redo Backup" to a usb drive. I had to cancel the backup, and the files could not be deleted. The files were in the Trash and still on my external drive, but I could'nt delete any of those, even as root.

My solutuion was to boot Windows (I still use it for playing games), and then I could delete the files. Maybe booting from a Live CD helps, or you plug the USB drive to a other computer running a diferent OS. I know this is a bit lame, but it was the quickest solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Open the disk utility(Type "disk" in search and click on the first application) then after opening of the application click on your pendrive name 
[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2glg.png)

Then, click on the white space(In my case its written "Sony partition 1 32gb")
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnRpT.png)

Then, click on "setting" icon and select "Format Partition".The below screen will appear.Enter "volume name" and in "type" choose "for use with all systems and devices(FAT)" 
[screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANDeQ.png)

Then press "next" > press "format". You are done.

Answer (score 0):

For the case of emptying the trash on a pen drive, [this ubuntuforums.org page](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1406622.html) addresses a similar situation.

One solution discussed on that page is to select the **.Trash-1000** folder in the **File Manager** and then press **<Shift>-<Delete>**.

Upon doing this, the file manager pops up a dialog indicating the action is irreversible and queries whether to continue or not.

This solution is known to work on other Linux distributions.

Answer (score -1):

```
chmod +rx .Trash-1000 -R
rm -rf .Trash-1000
```

This should hopefully fix your issue, I had the problem few days back where even if I owned folder I couldn't delete content cause folder was not executable -R if u have recursive folders

Hope that does it for you

Comment: Unfortunately not, I still get the same message. Also, looks like the chmod has no effect at all. When I see in the .Trash properties (using Nautilus), it have a "-" in the "executable" box. And if I change it as sudo (using gnome-terminal), I get the same message about "read only".

Comment: well I don't know in that case, cause for folder to be deleted it needs to be executable (I've no idea why). You can try mounting USB with sudo and then sudo rm -rf .Trash <-- I never tried it myself