# Setup of two additional SSD drives in RAID 1

Tags: hard-drive, raid

I have an ubuntu 12.04 setup with two HDD that is setup in a software raid 1. Now I need to add two additional SSD drives for separate storage of some database files. They need to be setup in their own separate raid 1 array. Unfortunately I have no idea where and how to start? So from the beginning after having plugged the two drives in, and booted the server - then what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay i got it:

1) First list all drives: `sudo lshw -c storage -c disk`
and note down the drives that needs to be put into a new raid array (in my case /dev/sda and /dev/sdb)

1.1) If you need to find out what drives are already in a raid this can be done with `sudo cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` details about which drives they cover can be inspected with `sudo mdadm --query --detail /dev/md0` where /dev/md0 is the array you want to inspect.

2) Now use fdisk to format the drives and create partitions for each drive: `sudo fdisk /dev/sda` this is done for each drive (and they should of cause be setup equally)

- If the disk is not "clean" then press `d` and follow instructions to delete the current partitions (note all data will be lost on that disk!)
- Then press `n` to create a new partition.
- Press `p` for primary and `1` for one partition, and use the defaults (pressing `return`).
- Press `t` for type and set the partition type to fd (linux raid autodetect).
- press `w` for writing your changes and exit.

3) Create the RAID array: `sudo mdadm --create /dev/md3 --chunk=128 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1`

4) Format the array: `sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/md3`

5) Lookup the infor for the new array using method in step 1.1 and edit `sudo nano /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` accordingly with the following line for your new array `ARRAY /dev/md/3 metadata=1.2 UUID=f368e29e:b79c72bd:631ce90f:e3370f90 name=master-db:3`

6) Create a directory (mount dir) for the new drive `sudo mkdir /new_device`

7) Mount to fstab by editing `sudo nano /etc/fstab` with `/dev/md3  /new_device  auto   defaults  0 0`

8) Run `sudo mount -a`

Check that everything runs with: `sudo cat /proc/mdstat`

Some helpfull links: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID http://superuser.com/questions/230497/how-can-i-add-a-raid-1-array-in-ubuntu-10-04
[Which hard disk drive is which?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27997/which-hard-disk-drive-is-which)